# Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my project, I installed the "pymysql", but i am trying to use the "pymysql", but i try to use and gives the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

`pip install pymysql`

`import pymysql`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'`

Comment: try import pymysql.cursors

Comment: I tried to do it but I couldn't. Gives the following error: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql' ```

Comment: was there an error message when you install it? You could also try tp update it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my pc too it took me 1 day :)
So go to your cmd or terminal and write:

```sh
pip uninstall pymysql
python -m pip --upgrade pip 
pip install pymysql
```

This will fix it as the version of pip u are using cant build a wheel for the module

Hope u will fix it :)

Comment: then python -m pip --upgrade pip pip install pymysql