# (Linux , Python) still face `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'` after pip install

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pip

still face `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'` after pip install

```
[root@localhost ~]# pip show pymysql
Name: PyMySQL
Version: 1.0.2
Summary: Pure Python MySQL Driver
Home-page: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/
Author: yutaka.matsubara
Author-email: yutaka.matsubara@gmail.com
License: "MIT"
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
[root@localhost ~]# pip show mysql-connector-python
Name: mysql-connector-python
Version: 8.0.31
Summary: MySQL driver written in Python
Home-page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html
Author: Oracle and/or its affiliates
Author-email:
License: GNU GPLv2 (with FOSS License Exception)
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: protobuf
Required-by:
[root@localhost ~]# pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
mysql-connector        2.2.9
mysql-connector-python 8.0.31
pip                    21.3.1
protobuf               3.19.6
PyMySQL                1.0.2
setuptools             59.6.0
```

- checking pip version
  that I also did uograde pip then unistall pymysql and mysql-connector-python, and install twice
  follow the discussion [Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381054/error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pymysql) but not working

```
[root@localhost ~]# pip -V
pip 21.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
[root@localhost ~]# pip3 -V
pip 21.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

---

.html

```
<h> New product</h>


<p>content</p>

<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
      <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <b><p>title test 1.10-test_get_ print  </p></b>
    <br>


  
    <py-script>

      import pymysql
      print (pymysql.__version__)
      
      
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- website output
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/) framework, where the Python installation is on the server side of a third-party service and has nothing to do with your local Python installation.

You should therefore follow PyScript's documentation of [Importing the needed libraries](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#importing-the-needed-libraries) to declare the libraries you wish to install with the `py-config` tag:

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
      <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <b><p>title test 1.10-test_get_ print  </p></b>
    <br>
    <py-config>
      packages = ["pymysql", "mysql-connector-python"]
    </py-config>
    <py-script>
      import pymysql
      print (pymysql.__version__)
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, one more thing, cause I simplize the question, if between ` <py-script> import mysql.connector</py-script>` and also error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'` , the same solution work?

Comment: such as `<py-config>
      packages = ["pymysql"]
      packages = ["mysql.connector"]
    </py-config>`

Comment: You should specify the package name instead, and in the same list as the other packages. I've updated my answer to reflect that. You can accept this answer by clicking on the grey check mark next to the answer if you find this answer to be helpful.